# How to transfer an external IP to other google cloud account?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I need to transfer an external IP to another Google Cloud account.

1. Provider account:
   a) It has a domain: providerxxx.com
   b) It has a specific billing account
   c) And it has a specific external static IP ipv4 (us-west1) that I want to keep: xyz.xyz.xyz.xyz

To move a service between companies I need to keep the IP address.

2. Receiving account:
   a) It has an own domain: receiverxxx.com
   b) It has an own billing account
   c) And I need to move the IP address (xyz.xyz.xyz.xyz) to this account.

How do I do this?

Thanks!
Felipe

Comment: Move the project that controls the IP address to your Google Cloud organization. If that is not acceptable, then you will need to contact Google Cloud support.

Comment: Thanks! It's looking simpler.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible to transfer your external IP to another Google Cloud account.

> To bring your own IP to Google, you create a public advertised prefix
> (PAP). Verification of ownership is done for this public advertised
> prefix using ROA and reverse DNS validation.  After verification is
> complete, we configure the announcement of this prefix to the
> internet, but the prefix is not advertised until it is provisioned.
> It takes up to four weeks for the public advertised prefix to be
> provisioned.
>
> While you wait for the public advertised prefix to provision, you
> split the prefix into public delegated prefixes (PDP), which you
> configure to have regional or global scope. You can then either divide
> the public delegated prefix further, or use it to create assignable IP
> addresses. It takes up to four weeks for the public delegated prefix
> to be provisioned.

You have more information about it on this [link](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/bring-your-own-ip).

Kind regards.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It's looking simpler to migrate the project as was done in the comment.